# How to resolve error in debugging a program in totalview?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, totalview

I installed TotalView on Ubuntu. For the begining I just tried to debug a very simple Hello Word program in but I got the following error:
"Fatal Error: Can't set up library cache directory -- cannot debug this target.  Do you want to run the TotalView Diagnostic Tool?"
I don't know what is the library cache directory. Any idea about the library cache directory in ubuntu can be helpful.